# Retrieve data before and after dash (-) in JSON string?

Tags: ios, json, nsstring

I'm wondering it is possible to retrieve the data before and after a "dash" in the retrieved json string. For example, this is the json string:

```
    {
        "position" : "1", 
        "artist" : "Avicii - Stories", 
        noWeeks" : "32", 

        },
```

I would like to make an NSString "Avicii" without the "- Stories." And in reverse, I'd like another NSString "Stories" without the "Avicii -"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here dict1 is your json dictionary data.

```
NSString *str=[[[dict1 objectForKey:@"artist"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

str contains the string "Avicii"

Comment: r u checked the string contain space can u update your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSArray *arr =[@"Avicii - Stories" componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
```

**Note**

There should be spaces before and after `-` , otherwise it wont work. If the string is `Avicii- Stories` or `Avicii -Stories` or `Avicii-Stories` , this method failed to separate the components and return a`nil` array. So i will suggest to use above method like so -

```
NSArray *arr =[@"Avicii - Stories" componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

and remove whitespace.

Comment: havent r u checked the string contain space can u update your answer

Comment: well answer updated. But keep in mind there should be spaces before and after `-`. otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

if it is already in your string

**choice-1**

```
NSString *GetAvicii = @"Avicii - Stories"
NSArray  *getArra = [GetAvicii componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
NSString *finalStr = getArra.firstObject; // or use getArra[0] // or use [getArra objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: This got rid of the space for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way.

```
NSString *artist = @"Avicii - Stories";
NSArray *artistArray = [artist componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
NSString *subString = [artistArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",subString);
```

Comment: r u checked the string contain space can u update your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *artistInfo = [@"Avicii - Stories" componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];

NSString *singer = artistInfo.firstObject;
NSString *song = artistInfo.lastObject;
```